# If $H_i(U_j)=0$ for infinitely many $j$ then $H_i(X)=0$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $U_i$ open subsets. If $U_i\subset U_{i+1}$ and $\bigcup^{\infty}_{i=1}U_i=X$. How can I prove that if for infinitely many $j$, the $i$-th homology vanishes $H_i(U_j)=0$, then $H_i(X)=0$?

Comment: Could you please write your question correctly? What are $X$, $U_i$, $H_i$??

Comment: Fixed it as you said

Answer (score 6):

This is true under some mild assumptions using the relationship between unions of spaces and direct limits of homology groups. See Proposition 3.33 of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology.

Comment: I find these "mild" assumptions rather strong — in particular they are not satisfied if $X$ is compact.

Comment: @abx If $X$ is compact then the question asked is trivial.

Comment: @abx Those conditions are always satisfied if the subspaces $X_\alpha$ (in Hatcher's notation) are open. So this actually gives a complete answer to the question asked.

Comment: @Wojuwu: OK, right.